# Is it possible to have an default uuid value which could show that the uuid is not valid

Tags: scala

I am creating a `case class`. I want to define default values to its fields. One of the fields in `uuid`. What could be a default value I could give it to signify that the user didn't give an `uuid`?

So far I have used `Option[UUID]` which works but it made me wonder if there could be some default value of `UUID` as well?

Comment: See the meaning. _universally unique identifier, UUID_ I think if there exist any default and same value then it is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main purpose of the `Option` class is to deal with values that may or may not be present. So in the case where a uuid may or may not be provided, using `Option[UUID]` is the correct approach. This is better than picking one UUID to mean "undefined".